# It crash in libcrypto.so.3 , how to debug it

Tags: openssl, libcrypto

'1: 2023-09-01 13:36:59 the killed daemon is /bin/xxq:

2: 2023-09-01 13:36:59 the killed daemon is /bin/aad:

5: 2023-09-01 13:40:25 <03376> firmware TEST-VM64-KVM

6: 2023-09-01 13:40:25 (Debug)

7: 2023-09-01 13:40:25 <03376> application newtest

8: 2023-09-01 13:40:25 <03376> *** signal 11 (Segmentation fault) received ***

9: 2023-09-01 13:40:25 <03376> Register dump:

10: 2023-09-01 13:40:25 <03376> RAX: 0000000000000009   RBX: 00007fe47d87b000

11: 2023-09-01 13:40:25 <03376> RCX: 00007fe47d87b130   RDX: fffffffffffd9ef0

12: 2023-09-01 13:40:25 <03376> R08: 00007fe47d87b094   R09: 0000000004400000

13: 2023-09-01 13:40:25 <03376> R10: 0000000000000009   R11: 00007ffee143ede8

14: 2023-09-01 13:40:25 <03376> R12: 00007ffee143ef14   R13: 00007ffee143ee70

15: 2023-09-01 13:40:25 <03376> R14: 0000000000000010   R15: fffffffffffffff5

16: 2023-09-01 13:40:25 <03376> RSI: 0000000011067fd0   RDI: 0000000011067d50

17: 2023-09-01 13:40:25 <03376> RBP: 0000000011067d50   RSP: 00007ffee143edd0

18: 2023-09-01 13:40:25 <03376> RIP: 00007fe4832f6d2e   EFLAGS: 0000000000010293

19: 2023-09-01 13:40:25 <03376> CS:  0033   FS: 0000   GS: 0000

20: 2023-09-01 13:40:25 <03376> Trap: 000000000000000e   Error: 0000000000000006

21: 2023-09-01 13:40:25 <03376> OldMask: 0000000000000000

22: 2023-09-01 13:40:25 <03376> CR2: 0000000011068000

23: 2023-09-01 13:40:25 <03376> stack: 0x7ffee143edd0 - 0x7ffee14589c0

24: 2023-09-01 13:40:25 <03376> Backtrace:

25: 2023-09-01 13:40:25 <03376> [0x7fe4832f6d2e] => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.3

26: 2023-09-01 13:40:25 liboffset 000cbd2e

27: 2023-09-01 13:40:25 <03376> [0x7fe48351432c] => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.3

28: 2023-09-01 13:40:25 liboffset 002e932c

29: 2023-09-01 13:40:25 <03376> [0x7fe48356172c] => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.3

30: 2023-09-01 13:40:25 liboffset 0033672c

`31: 2023-09-01 13:40:25 <03376> [0x7fe48341a60e] => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.3`

`32: 2023-09-01 13:40:25 (EVP_DecryptUpdate+0x0000009e) liboffset 001ef60e'`

Comment: See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  What you have posted is pretty useless for someone else - it provides almost no information.  As currently posted, this question is going to get closed rapidly.  You can use the `Edit` button to update your question with more data.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.